# Problem when importing an FBX into blender

Tags: python, import, error, .fbx

I'm getting an error when importing an FBX who contain a complex RIG into blender 2.92.
Any ideas on how to resolve? I'm lacking knowledge on python code..[image]

Comment: This appears to be a bug either in your FBX file or in the importer code.  Can you share the FBX file?

Comment: Sorry i can't, it's for a work project so i'm not authorized to share with people.. But it's a complex RIG and as far as i understand the error, it appears that Blender is not able to enumerate the props and the empty, am i right?